# excluding a row from a mysql database outputting

Tags: php, mysql

Every third element extracted from the database will output in the large box, while every other element will output in the small box. What I need it to do is exclude the third element when the small box is outputted. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if($i % 3 == 0) {
// large box
echo '<div class="box" style="width: 692px; height: 218px">' . $array['feedName'] . '</div>';
}
// small box
echo '<div class="box" style="width: 246px; height: 218px">' . $array['feedName'] . "<br></div>";
// exclude the third element
$i++;
}
}
```

Comment: Use `else`: `if ($i % 3 == 0) {large} else {small}`

Comment: Yeah I had tried an elseif before but the code logic didn't make sense so it didn't do anything.

Comment: Just use `else`, not `elseif` as you do not have a second condition. See in the [PHP Manual: elseif](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) about how it works.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby If you got it working some other way, feel free to include your own answer below and mark as correct so others can see how you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
divide by 6 and get the remainder (%)
if (remainder == 0 or 3) {
    large box
} else if (remainder == 1 or 5) {
    small box
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want correctly (each third item is in the large box and kept out of the small box), you just use an `else` clause in your `if`.

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    if($i % 3 == 0) {
        // large box
        echo '<div class="box" style="width: 692px; height: 218px">' . $array['feedName'] . '</div>';
    }
    else {
        // small box
        echo '<div class="box" style="width: 246px; height: 218px">' . $array['feedName'] . "<br></div>";
    }

    $i++;
}
```